# How to get the objects from inside an objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, element, curly-braces

I have *objects* inside an *object* returned from a REST API as such:

```
const json = { 
"0": {
"barcode": "897382173",
"img": "-",
"name": "Lemon",
"productId": "DC-PR111113"
},

 "1": {
"barcode": "697382173",
"img": "-",
"name": "Aloe",
"productId": "DC-PR111113"}
}
```

there is a curly-braces at the start and at the end

> And I need to take those objects (0 and 1) out, and place it in array like this

```
const json = [
"0": {
"barcode": "897382173",
"img": "-",
"name": "Lemon",
"productId": "DC-PR111113"
},


 "1": {
"barcode": "697382173",
"img": "-",
"name": "Aloe",
"productId": "DC-PR111113"}
}
]
```

I tried so many things but still have no luck :(

Comment: `Object.values(json)`?

Comment: That question is about Python @Tyr, this one is about JavaScript.